# civ6 patch not updating

Tags: steam, civilization-6

I am running civ 6 build `1.0.0.26 (143190)` on my Mac. Purchased it using Steam.

How can I either confirm that I am running the latest build or force update?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that Steam is not in offline mode. Then try to launch the game.

If the game is not up-to-date, it will update before launching the game. If the game is up-to-date it will just run.

Comment: Hmm, Steam was running in 'online' mode. I forced online->offline->online but still am running same version. No update triggered :(